# Get the latest update date & it's related infomation

Tags: oracle11g

I have this query problem. Hope someone can help

Given below the table is `Country Rates`

```
 ID     Country   Date        Rate 
 ----------------------------------     
 1.    CANADA  03/02/2009    0.78
 2.    UK      12/07/2009    1.23
 3.    UK      03/02/2010    0.12
 4.    USA     05/11/2010    1.63
 5.    CANADA  03/02/2010    0.52
 6.    USA     05/02/2011    0.98
```

I want to get the latest date & it related rate

Results should be like this:

```
Country   Date        Rate 
---------------------------    
UK      03/02/2010    0.12
CANADA  03/02/2010    0.52
USA     05/02/2011    0.98
```

So I want the SQK for get this results

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Malikaa-

Assuming your table is structured like this:

```
CREATE TABLE RATES
(
  COUNTRY  VARCHAR2(10),
  DT       DATE,
  RATE     NUMBER
)
```

then you could run this to get your answer:

```
SELECT O.COUNTRY, O.RATE, O.DT
FROM RATES O JOIN
(
    SELECT COUNTRY, MAX(DT) DT
    FROM RATES
    GROUP BY COUNTRY) I
ON O.COUNTRY = I.COUNTRY
AND O.DT = I.DT
```

Hope this helps.

-CJ

Answer (score 0):

Here are two alternative ways of doing this.  The First is a bit neater and the second a bit faster, both also come with the bonus of columns in the order you want ;)

```
WITH latest_dates
    AS (SELECT country, max(dt) AS dt FROM rates GROUP BY country)
SELECT l.country, l.dt, r.rate FROM latest_dates l
LEFT JOIN rates r ON l.country=r.country AND l.dt = r.dt;
```

or

```
SELECT r.country, r.dt, r.rate
FROM rates r
LEFT OUTER JOIN rates l ON l.country = r.country AND l.dt > r.dt
WHERE l.dt IS NULL;
```

You should note that all three (these two and CJ's code) will return too many rows when there is more that one rate for a country on the same day, but work for the dataset you give.